# Avoid reloading of data in Bigquery if content already exists in Table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, etl

I am writing a airfllow pipeline.
I need to write dag, such that it loads content of csv file to Bigquery Table, but if the content already present in table, it discard that file.
I know we can do it with computing hash of file in normal programming, but don't have any idea about how to do with Airflow and Bigquery.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What if some rows are present but not all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the **write_desposition= WRITE_EMPTY** in the load job configuration to avoid loading the data into an already existing/populated table.

Using the below sample code I tried to load the data into a table:

```
import os

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryDeleteDatasetOperator,
)
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_DATASET_NAME", 'airflow_test')
TABLE_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_TABLE_NAME", 'gcs_to_bq_table')

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='example_gcs_to_bigquery_operator',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['example'],
)

create_test_dataset = BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator(
    task_id='create_airflow_test_dataset', dataset_id=DATASET_NAME, dag=dag
)

# [START howto_operator_gcs_to_bigquery]
load_csv = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bigquery_example',
    bucket='cloud-samples-data',
    source_objects=['bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'post_abbr', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    dag=dag,
)

load_csv1 = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bigquery_example_again',
    bucket='cloud-samples-data',
    source_objects=['bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name': 'post_abbr1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY',
    dag=dag,
)

create_test_dataset >> load_csv >> load_csv1
```

During the 1st load task, data will be loaded into the specified BigQuery table. But when we try to load data again (2nd load task) into the same table with **write_disposition= WRITE_EMPTY**, the task fails since the destination table is not empty. So, the data will not be loaded.

**Note: “write_disposition”** does not account for the data(contents of the file), rather just checks if the destination table is empty or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the GCSToBigQueryOperator, there's an argument named `write_disposition`, which controls what to do if the destination table already exists. You have 3 options here:

- `"WRITE_TRUNCATE"`: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data and uses the schema from the query result.
- `"WRITE_APPEND"`: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.
- `"WRITE_EMPTY"`: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.

I believe you're looking for `WRITE_EMPTY`.

This works on the table-level. If you want more fine-grained control over when to (not) discard, you'll need to write some logic yourself and trigger a job for that from Airflow.

Docs/examples:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/gcs.html